# problems with children escaping parent divs using ems and %

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a site that I've been using ems and % in as I want to make it responsive. It's my first time attempting this.
I had the same site working using px.

I'm having this issue where content in the header and footer is not re-sizing properly. The content moves down past their containers or overlaps other content.

I.e. say in my footer i have the parent content set to 100% width and then the children divs set to various percentages of it.

The children then move down out of their containers and even the footer itself when I re-size.

Here's [My JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/unt5zbL8/5/)

In my code here I've just put the footer code as it will just look messy if I put it all

```
<footer class="site-footer">
<div class="leftfoot">
<div class="footercontent">

            <div class="logocopyright">
      <a href="index.html"> Tali.Zorah 2015 &copy;</a>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="rightfoot">
  <div class="legal">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="legal.html">LEGAL NOTICE</a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.html">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>

   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="social">

  <ul class="socicons">
    <li>
      <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com"> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

And the footer CSS:

```
.footercontent{
 position:absolute;
 min-width:100%;
 max-width:100%;       
}

.logofooter{

 float:left;
 margin-left:2%;
 min-width: 10%;
 max-width: 10%;
 min-height:100%;

}
.mysitefooter-logo {
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width:10%;
 max-width:100%;
 margin-top: -1%;
 margin-right:1%;
}


.logocopyright{
 float:left;
 margin-top:5%;
 margin-left:2%;
 min-width:100%;
 padding-top:1%;

}
.leftfooter{
 min-width:10%;
 max-width:15%;
 float:left;
}
.rightfooter{
 min-width:85%;
 max-width:90%;
 float:right;
}
.logocopyright a {

 font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', Gadget, sans-serif; 
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size:.6em;
}
.logocopyright a:hover{
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px;
 border-radius: 200px;
 background: #1874CD; 
}


.legal{
 background-color:#009;
 min-width:70%;
 max-width:80%;
 float:left;

}

.legal a:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px;
 border-radius: 200px;
 background: #1874CD;  
}
.legal ul li {
 display:inline-block;
 font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', Gadget, sans-serif;
 font-size:.8em;
 margin-left:8%;
 min-width:10%;
 max-width:100%;
}
.legal ul > :first-child {
 margin-left:5%;
}
.legal a {
  font-size:1em;
  color:#FFF;

}
.social{
 min-width:15%;
 max-width:20%;
 float:right;
 margin-top: -4%;
 color:#000000;

}

.social li {

    display:inline-block;

}
.socicons{
    min-width:80%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.socicons li{
    display:inline;
}
.facebook{
    min-width:8%;
    max-width:10%;
}
.facebook img
{
    min-width:8%;
    max-width:20%;   
}
.twitter{
    min-width:8%;
    max-width:10%;
}
.twitter img
{
    min-width:8%;
    max-width:20%;

}
.instagram{
    min-width:8%;
    max-width:10%;
}
.instagram img
{
    min-width:8%;
    max-width:20%;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a responsive site absolute positioning is not a good idea. Just use a width of 100% and try using viewport(vw) width  instead of ems.

Comment: @Doctor can you give me an example please? Is the viewport not in the HTML and set to 1? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: this is how I would do just a straight forward footer you may need to adapt for your needs.

Comment: #footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 5%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2vw;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444343 0%, #282828 40%, #000000 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444343 0%, #282828 40%, #000000 100%);
        color: white;

Comment: so I don't need the minus margin for the footer in the page wrap with this approach? So it stays at the bottom

Comment: No as long as say for example you have a header with a height 15%

Comment: content with height of 80% and a footer with height of 5% it should stay at the bottom.

Comment: Something else you might like to take a look at is the display:flex attribute.       https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: My pleasure TaliZorah.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I fixed a little. I updated:

- 'id' into footer tag.
- little jscript.

here's my js code:

```
var footer =  document.getElementById("guestAttempt");
footer.setAttribute("float","left");
footer.setAttribute("margin-left","3em");
footer.setAttribute("margin-bottom","0em");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/unt5zbL8/6/embedded/result/

Comment: I really appreciate the help but I'm looking for a purely css approach as my Javascript skills are very limited.

Comment: then just do this, footer{ float: left; margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0;} it would work same as I suggested before.